# ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (256, 256, 256)

Tags: tensorflow, flask, conv-neural-network, reshape, valueerror

So I am working on a project Brain Tumor Detection using CNN. I have a model that takes 4 parameters as an input (BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, CHANNELS) to make predictions. My model works fine with most of the images but with some images, it gives error as
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (256, 256, 256)

I have done image resizing(256,256) and reshaping(1,256,256,3) and still, I get the error. I have looked for an answer on google but couldn't find any reasonable answer. What could be the problem? I would appreciate any help. Screenshots of my model and the error are attached for reference.
Thanks!!

```
# Model
input_shape = (BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, CHANNELS)
n_classes = 2

model = models.Sequential([
    resize_and_rescale,
    
    layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    
    layers.Conv2D(64,  kernel_size = (3,3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    
    layers.Conv2D(64,  kernel_size = (3,3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    
    layers.Flatten(),
    
    layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax'),
])

model.build(input_shape=input_shape)
```

```
# Function used in flask for deploying
def prediction():
    img = request.files['img']
    img.save("img.jpg")
    image = Image.open("img.jpg")
    x = np.array(image.resize((256,256)))
    # x = x.reshape(1,256,256,3)
    x = np.expand_dims(x,axis=0)
    res = (model.predict_on_batch(x))
    classification = np.where(res == np.amax(res))[1][0]
    # a=names(classification)
    a=str(res[0][classification]*100) + '% Confidence ' + names(classification)

    return render_template("prediction.html", data=a)
```

Comment: Then input shape does not contain the batch shape.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `input_shape = (BATCH_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, CHANNELS)` to `input_shape = (IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, CHANNELS)`, as the batch size parameter is automatically inferred.

Comment: If I change the code as you said then do I need to do np.expand_dims(IMG,axis=0) or not. Because when I remove Batch_size, input_shape has only 3 parameters. But you said batch parameter is automatically inferred. So does this mean the input_shape will still have 4 parameters?

Comment: Yes, the inferred size will be (None, height, width, number_of_channels). And yes, when you predict on a single photo, you need np.expand_dims(img,axis=0)